# What is diffrence between CSS frameworks and preprocessors?

Tags: css

I know Bootstrap and Foundation are CSS frameworks, but I'm not sure whether LESS and SASS are CSS frameworks or preprocessors.

What is the difference between CSS frameworks and preprocessors?

Comment: check here http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/what-is-a-difference-in-css-frameworks-vs-preprocessors

Answer (score 2):

From http://lesscss.org/:

> Less is a CSS pre-processor, meaning that it extends the CSS language,
>   adding features that allow variables, mixins, functions and many other
>   techniques that allow you to make CSS that is more maintainable,
>   themable and extendable.

From http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

> Sass is an extension of CSS that adds power and elegance to the basic
>   language. It allows you to use variables, nested rules, mixins, inline
>   imports, and more, all with a fully CSS-compatible syntax. Sass helps
>   keep large stylesheets well-organized, and get small stylesheets up
>   and running quickly, particularly with the help of the Compass style
>   library.

Basically both are css pre-processors, as in they allow you to write style information that later compiles to css.

Frameworks, like bootstrap, on the other hand are more like pre-made style sheets that can be used to save development time. Rather than writing out custom sheets with similar styles over and over again, you can make use of prefabricated sheets. They usually have things like resets, basic layouts, and/or grid systems built in.

There are also some frameworks written in, and designed to be used with a pre-proccessor like [Less Framework 4](http://lessframework.com/)

If you're relatively new to this stuff, I would recommend starting with plain old css. Pre-processors can be helpful, but the learning curve is a bit steeper.

Comment: So, how does one go about learning the three things? Should it be like this: CSS -> Pre-processors (e.g. SASS) -> Frameworks (e.g. Bootstrap)?

Answer (score 1):

As said above, LESS and SASS allow CSS to follow the DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principles of coding.  For example if you had a CSS file where you wanted 12 items let's say; h1, h2, h3, h4, p, a, etc all to have the same color of text(let's say a salmon color), what these preprocessors allow you to do is create a variable(let's say **myColor**), that you can then pass into the color attribute of each of these items.
   This may not sound exciting, but where it really shines is when you want to say redesign the site or alter that color to say a 'sky blue' instead of now skimming through those 3000 lines of code to find those different items (h1, h2, ... , a, etc *as listed above*) you'd only need to change the **myColor** variable from the hex/rgb/rgba color code to the one for sky blue.  Which in turn would change that value for each of those items.
   So essentially you need to change 1 value that's easily found, as opposed to many, which may require a lot of sifting through code.

To note though, LESS and SASS cannot be read by a standard Internet browser, instead you must use a program that compiles your LESS/SASS code into standard CSS (these programs are easy to find and most programs such as Sublime, Brackets, Atom, etc have the functionality built in or allow a package to be downloaded that does it.)
   Then when you need to edit your code, you change the LESS/SASS file and recompile again.
   That's just the tip of what LESS/SASS can do, but it gives you an idea hopefully of their use.  Programmers are lazy, copy and pasting isn't a good option generally, as you violate the DRY principle.  So this is a happy medium explained hopefully in laymans terms.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to believe I can accomplish the same results as pre-processors using jQuery(the most popular ui/ux framework).

However, depending on how many people are working on one project it may a case of teams learned in SASS or LESS scripts and may not know jQuery syntax as well. They are only focused on CSS effects, which could be a plus.

If I .addClass() to multiple DOM elements with jQuery... it may be even more efficient than having a preprocessor duplicate desired code all over a css file.